# 2 PK samples for the same patient in Matlab Simbiology: how to calculate intra-individual variability?

Tags: matlab, simulink, modeling, mcmc, nlme

Sorry I'm new to MatLab's Simbiology toolbox!

I'm trying to build a population pharmacokinetics model that includes intra-individual variability / residual unexplained varibility.

Would anyone kindly advise how to input the data if I have two pharmacokinetics samples per patient, collected one week apart? In particular, I am not sure how to label the Group ID (ie. patient ID) for the same patient for different PK samples (taken a week apart).

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want SimBiology to use the same model parameters for both PK samples, then the measurements need to have the same ID. You just need to ensure that the time data is correctly defined so that the second